# How expensive is maintaining a TCP socket in java

Tags: java, tcp

I have currently implemented a heartbeat mechanism for my project and I am using TCP as my underlying connectivity. I was wondering how expensive is maintaining a tcp connection. Each slave sends a heartbeat every 5 seconds to the master(yes i know its way to often but i have a good reason to do so). So I was wondering should I constantly create a new connection or should I keep the connection open. Because if I keep the open connection then in that case I can just handle the exception. But since I need to know every 5 seconds wether or not a slave is down should I be re establishing the connection or just keep it open. Thanks in advance.

Comment: keep it open is more preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more expensive to re-open the connection regularly; there is a [three-way handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml) on open. Once the socket is open, that cost can be amortized (but only if you leave it open).

Comment: Will that even be true if I have 100's of slaves? because then I have a dedicated thread open for each of them. And the three way hand shake are just SYN-ACK packets is it that expensive? Just wondering? Thanks!!!

Comment: If you have 100s of slaves, then you should look into *multicast*. Opening the socket is the most expensive portion of using **TCP**. Other options include **UDP**. But you *specifically* asked about TCP.

Answer (score 2):

As previously stated reopening the connection is more expensive, unless there are other factors involved like mobility. Not only do you have a [three-way](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml) handshake, but you also have a [four-way](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm) handshake terminating the connection. In addition to this, your TCP server application likely open up new threads for each new connection, which also needs to be allocated, deallocated etc. 
Most likely your connection will also pass through firewalls which are often NATed, which in turn opens up ports and states. This is why I personally rarely use UDP, because UDP may have problems passing through firewalls and ISP filters.

Finally the maintenance of the TCP connection itself from a protocol point of view is minimal. TCP do have the option of *keep-alive*, but these are rarely sent as often as every 5 seconds. There is a small overhead of context switching within your OS process, but that would happen regardless of you opening and closing the connection.

Keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a heartbeat, why not use UDP, TCP requires confirmation of receipt, UDP does not, then you can have a listener and just receive any packets that are broadcast to it and process. meaning one port open on the main system no matter how many children are sending to it.

TCP you would require one connection per child.

Comment: My heartbeat manager checks wether the slave has been for 8 seconds or above. And since UDP is unreliable if I miss the heartbeat my heartbeat manager will flag the worker as down even though it is not!!!

Comment: So you allow 2-3 contacts before marking down. On the system i work on we have a keep alive message, and if we miss 1 contact (15 seconds) we go into recovery mode for that device until we miss the second contact then we mark it as down - and these are async messages

Comment: BTW this is the system i work on http://image.slidesharecdn.com/homelandsecurity2013lisivo3-140204080445-phpapp02/95/security-in-large-strategic-and-complex-systems-43-638.jpg?cb=1391501394